# Excel VBA - Type mismatch - ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I created an Excel VBA Macro to upload the excel file to Sharepoint site and update the document properties values.

The macro works perfect for USA users, but for European users, they get "Type Mismatch" error on the following line:

```
Sub Properties()
    ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Business Line").Value = Range("B7")
End Sub
```

I also tried

```
Sub Properties()
   For Each prop In ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties
      If prop.Name = "Business Line" Then
         prop.Value = Range("B7")
      End If
   Next prop
End Sub
```

but European users still have the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

thanks for your support

CY

Comment: This is impossible to fix without knowing what is inside B7. Also show us the rest of the code please.

Comment: B7 only contains a single word, "Gas". What bothers me is the same code with same B7 work for USA users, but not for European users. Actually, there is no the rest of the code, I updated my post to have the complete code...This simple code just doesn't work on European Excels.... very strange. And we all use Excel 2016 32-bit version. –

Comment: How about using Range(B7).text or .value?